# For a particular location gmap doesn't return lat lon

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

For this particular place  gmap not return lat/lon "Absa Centre,
Riebeek Street, Cape Town, South Africa" 
I am using this code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var address = "Absa Centre, Riebeek Street, Cape Town, South Africa";

geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
   var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
    var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
    alert(latitude+' '+longitude);
    } 
}); 
</script>
```

anyone have suggestion ?

Comment: do you get any console error? and have you tried for any other location

Answer (score 1):

"Absa Centre, Riebeek Street, Cape Town, South Africa" is not a postal address, it is a "place".

Use the Places API to find it, use its address (2 Riebeek St, Cape Town City Centre, Cape Town, 8001, South Africa), or use its PlaceId ("ChIJx9Oa_2BnzB0RSoIzDuPzdrU") in the geocoder.

[Places API](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=Absa%20Centre,%20Riebeek%20Street,%20Cape%20Town,%20South%20Africa&place=1)

[Address](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=2%20Riebeek%20St,%20Cape%20Town%20City%20Centre,%20Cape%20Town,%208001,%20South%20Africa&geocode=1)

**code snippet using geocoder with placeId:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var address = "Absa Centre, Riebeek Street, Cape Town, South Africa";
  var placeId = "ChIJx9Oa_2BnzB0RSoIzDuPzdrU";

  geocoder.geocode({
    // 'address': address
    placeId: placeId
  }, function(results, status) {

    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
      var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      if (results[0].geometry.viewport) map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport);
      else if (results[0].geometry.bounds) map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.bounds);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
      })
    } else alert("Not found, status=" + status);
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```